# Does BlueBox "Fake ID" vulnerability break protectionLevel: "Signature"?

Tags: android

Referring to this vuln:

http://bluebox.com/technical/android-fake-id-vulnerability/

and this permission:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html

> "signature"   A permission that the system grants only if the requesting
>   application is signed with the same certificate as the application
>   that declared the permission. If the certificates match, the system
>   automatically grants the permission without notifying the user or
>   asking for the user's explicit approval.